# Finding faces in a jpg file using android

Tags: android, face-detection

I already have searched on this site for finding the face/s in an image. But got no luck. I am using following code --

```
private static final int MAX_FACES = 10; 
private static final String IMAGE_FN = "/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg"; 
private Bitmap background_image; 
FaceDetector face_detector;
private FaceDetector.Face faces[]; 
private int face_count; 

BitmapFactory.Options bitmap_options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
bitmap_options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
background_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(IMAGE_FN, bitmap_options); 
int width = background_image.getWidth();
int height = background_image.getHeight();
face_detector = new FaceDetector( width, height, MAX_FACES); 
faces = new FaceDetector.Face[MAX_FACES];
face_count = 0;
face_count = face_detector.findFaces(background_image, faces);
```

But, still I am not getting the correct face count in an image.
Could anyone find the flaw in the code? Or do you think that It should work??

Comment: how many faces are in your image and how many faces did it detect?

Comment: If image has one face, it shows 2.
If image has 4, it shows 3....random in nature.